# How to email any chart using Highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

If I include exporting.js file in my script, I get options like 'Print Chart' and 'Download  Image'.

Is there any way to get an option like 'Email Chart', that will open up the preferred email client and attach the chart as an image?

Comment: you cannot add attachments to the email raised with `mailto:`. There are other ways like ActiveX or similar but with just JS you cannot do that.

Comment: Highcharts supports generating charts on server side as well. Can this help?

Comment: it can help. But still you will need to store this image on your server and prefill the email with a URL to this image. still it cannot be an attachment...

Comment: Just the same way as it is done on Highcharts Cloud service: https://cloud.highcharts.com/charts/acovyh (mail on the left side).

Comment: @Pawel, it only adds a link to the page in email body. Chart itself isn't attached.

Comment: Yes, that was my point. It is an example for @simon suggestion.

Comment: ok thanks. I will do something similar.

Comment: download image before sending and attach it to the email, reffering to it in the HTML to embed it in the email body. Here's a short python implementation for sending images - I personally use that with matplotlib
http://datamakessense.com/easy-scheduled-emailing-with-python-for-typical-bi-needs/

Answer (score 0):

Save the rendered chart in a JS variable. Ajax it to phpmailer and send it via an email.

Works in gmail safari, but not chrome/mozilla.  Also works when opened in Workspace email.

[image: godaddy]

```
$(document).on("trigger", function() {

    var chart = $('#print').html();
    var email = $('#email').val();
    $.post("../client/makereport.php", {print: chart, email: email});
})
```