# Sending Generated Highchart image via email

Tags: javascript, email, highcharts, phantomjs, html-email

I am trying to send chart via email using pahntomjs and highcharts, So far, I have been able to generate images using the code here https://github.com/vgno/highcharts-png-renderer
I need to be able to generate these chart images dynamically for up to 1k users and attach the generated image to an email template that will be sent to the user. Please what tools or code repos can I  use to achieve this. I am primarily a C# developer but I'm open to any suggestions.

Thank you

Comment: I think that the title's question and the associated tags are misleading. One thing is exporting the image which can be achieved by Highcharts exporting module http://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/export-module-overview. The next thing is sending the image via email (in general) and it depends on the specific backend technology you use.

Comment: The following links may be helpful for sending you in the right direction: 1) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30303327/how-to-email-any-chart-using-highcharts; 2) https://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api/suggestions/3486907-email-send-option-when-chart-is-generated. You may have to export the charts using a server-side solution, which can then be sent to your preferred email system.

Comment: @user2721794 are you still facing this issue?

Answer (score 1):

#### Highcharts Java Approach

I found an interesting article about it in the [highcharts blog](https://www.highcharts.com/blog/news/52-serverside-generated-charts/).

The solution provided is to:

> For running Highcharts on the server, we need to emulate a browser environment on the server. For this, we use PhantomJS, a headless WebKit with JavaScript API. The Phantom process takes our [highcharts-convert.js](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/blob/master/exporting-server/java/highcharts-export/highcharts-export-convert/target/classes/phantomjs/highcharts-convert.js) script as an argument plus command line parameters. With the command line parameters, we pass over the Highcharts configuration, the name of the output file and parameters for the graphical layout. Example usage:

```
phantomjs highcharts-convert.js -infile options.json -outfile chart.png -scale 2.5 -width 300 -constr Chart -callback callback.js
```

[image: Render charts on the server]

You can refer to this [github repo](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/exporting-server/java/highcharts-export/highcharts-export-convert/target/classes/phantomjs) for some `phantomjs` scripts prepared by the Highcharts team itself

#### Highcharts NodeJS Approach

Highcharts [released last December an `npm package`](https://www.highcharts.com/blog/news/256-introducing-the-highcharts-node-js-export-server/) for server side chart generation in NodeJS.

> As with the Java export server, the node one can run either as a command line interface, or as a stand-alone http(s) server. The command line switches (and POST options if running in server mode) are fully compatible with the existing export servers – with a few additional ones.
>   The CLI mode also replaces the old highcharts-convert.js PhantomJS script.

You can refer to the [github repo](https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server)

#### C# Blog Approach

The previous example was expecting you to use `Java` or a `NodeJS` export-server. In this [blog post](http://www.ryansouthgate.com/2016/02/11/c-server-side-rendering-with-highcharts/) you can find another implementation done with a C# server - which seems to be more suitable to you